# Ramset powder concrete nail gun

Tags: concrete

My nails are going flush but the little orange part is stuck between washer and nail. What's best way to get them off. Some came off when fired others stuck.

Comment: ...ignore them, if your nails are set flush.

Comment: Will they get in the way when hanging drywall?